# How to return from shell script with return value 1 with successful completion of script

Tags: shell

How to return from shell script with return value 1 with successful completion of script?

Comment: What shell environment are you using? If it's bash you'd exit 1?

Comment: Don't you think it might be a start to tell what shell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly, returning a value of 1 to indicate success is exactly the opposite of expected behavior, so you really should not do it.  However, if you want to, then just do

```
exit 1
```

However, this typically indicates failure, and you would do well to respect the convention.

Answer (score 2):

0 indicates success, non-zero indicates failure.
You should use exit or exit 0 in case of success. In case of failure, use exit 1. If you want to return information why your program has failed, you can use several different return values, i. e. 1, 2, 3, -1, 255, etc.